# Symfony2: annotation cache partially warm up

Tags: symfony, caching, annotations

From my Symfony2 application, when I access an ajax controller the first time, it is very slow (up to 5 sec) then it goes faster. My goal is to speed it up any time - even on the first time.

I checked the cache files and found that this is due to cached annotations. My workflow is:

- clear the cache
- warm up the cache => few annotation cache files are computed (603 files)
- access  a "normal" controller => it goes fast
- access this ajax controller => very slow the first time, additional cache files (1200) are generated
- access again the ajax controller => goes fast

I also tried to backup all annotation cache files, clear & warm up the cache, restore the annoation cache files => it goes fast on the first access.

So I am sure that my slow down issues are dues to the annoation cache files, that are only partially generated by the cache warm up.

The question is: how to generate fully?

Answer (score 1):

I finally built my own warmer. Thanks to https://github.com/gnugat/nomo-spaco I go through all classes of my projet, then I call the annotation_reader service on all reflected classes / methods / properties and it seems to be OK